# Dropbox folder name with parenthesis and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuildcommunitytasks, mklink

I am getting errors building a project that is in my dropbox folder. This happened recently when I linked my work dropbox and the path has parenthesis that is placed there by dropbox. I tried renaming the dropbox directory. I am certain that this is the cause because I moved the project to the desktop and was able to build straight away...

For some unknown reason the symbolic links I created using MKLINK stopped working. It is likely a dropbox change because I'm getting "Location is not available" errors when attempting to access the dropbox folder using the symbolic link on both of my windows machines. After further investigation this is actually resulting from a bug in MSBuild Community Tasks. 
bug:
https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/pull/64

workaround:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/713690/msbuild-4-0-usingtask-cannot-have-a-path-with-parentheses

Comment: Visual Studio error reads... "users\me\Dropbox%28Work%29\....

Answer (score 3):

In Command Prompt:

```
mklink /d \Dbox \Users\me\desktop\Dropbox
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx#BKMK_examples

This appears to eliminate the build errors generated by Visual Studio. I can now point my IIS sites to the symbolic link on the C drive called Dbox.